# Process flat files

Tags: .net, algorithm, c#-4.0

My service receive big txt flat files (40 mb) from many clients (can vary from 1 to 30 clients in a minute)
Each row must be converted to an entity if there aren't errors in a data format or data.
In a row there is not a delimiter, each row divided at fixed substring length, so each substring would be an entity's field.
so my question is how quickly parse huge txt flat files to an entities array?

Service is developed in C# 4.0. But algorithm can be developed in other language if it can have weak performance in C#

Comment: What kind of error checks you are planning to implement? In other words, what kind of errors you anticipate?

Comment: I should say that string contains mandatory and not mandatory fields. At step of converting rows to entities I anticipate next. 1. Wrong line length. 2. Wrong new line separator. 3. Data absence for mandatory fields 4. Wrong data format (datetime parse e.g.) 5. Absence data etc

Comment: Since you are not making any complex check, I think you should go with fastest and simplest language: C .

Comment: also I must check data with some dictionaries in database tables. But i think it would be better to do after parsing rows to entities.

Comment: So the lines are fixed-length, or each line contains a variable number of fixed-length fields?  The description of the file and the error checking necessary almost makes it sound like it's composed of fixed-length lines/fields that aren't necessarily fixed-length...

Comment: What fraction of files do you think will get rejected? If it is large, then you might want to run fast, but not complicated checks first (before entity extraction). Otherwise, do the entity extraction first.

Comment: ideally, the lines are fixed-length, but files are sent by outer clients and they can send wrong data. so there is no guarantee that I receive fixed-length rows or correct data

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of decision factors I'd have, here. If I had a final state in a database or XML, I'd probably use Altova's MapForce FlexText to create what looks like it'd be a simple mapping. That should be relatively performant, as well.

If I needed to parse into classes for processing first, though, I'd probably use a simple StreamReader and parse it line by line.

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath)) 
  {
      string line;

      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
      {
          ProcessLine(line);
      }
  }
```

Comment: but files can be with errors. there is no a guarantee that data in files is correct

Comment: Then FlexText is probably not a good fit. I'd put the validation in the ProcessLine method.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a quick test which created and dumped .5 million objects with 8 properties in to a text file (1 per row) I padded these to fixed lengths and converted int values to string where required. The resulting rows made a 50mb file.

Reading this back in and creating the instances of the objects, parsing int's etc took about 3 secs on my PC (no high perf counters used).

I used a streamreader as Jacob suggested too, but I think ultimately a lot of this will depend on your hardware, the complexity of the error checks involved, how many rows it is and what you want to do with the objects once you have them.

Not sure if that helps!

Comment: c#. My PC is a q6600 quad core (obviously this was single threaded), you could probably do something funky with multi core processing different files. I also tried on different disks, I have 1 as SSD and 1 is standard. both came out similar performance, i dont think the disk was a bottle neck for 50mbs